# start Icecast2 from PHP?

Tags: php, server, vps, icecast, internet-radio

I request that someone can give me adequate guidance on what I am trying to do. Well, let me explain.

I want to start the icecast2 server through php, (we know that it starts only by default for a single port) but in my case I want to control for example port 8002, 8004, 8006 to give it start from php.

I have done this same function with shoutcast, and with shoutcast if it starts and stops the server.

it would be something like this in a vps, taking into account that for icecast it would be in: `` `/ home / icecast / 8002``` and so on ...

in shoutcast I have it like this ...

`` `/ home / shoutcast / 9002``` and other ports ... how do I start and stop it in shoutcast? simple.

I create 2 files:

1. on.ph which has the following code:

`'' shell_exec ('./ sc_serv9002'); header ('Location: "desired path after executing command');` ''

or also by calling a file called start9002.sh with 777 permissions that contains the path to start shoutcast (`` `/ home / shoutcast / 9002 / sc_serv / home / shoutcast / 9002 / sc_serv.conf```)

`'' shell_exec ('./ start9002.sh'); header ('Location: "desired path after executing command');` ''

2. the off.php (which will turn off the specific shoutcast port like this.

`'' shell_exec ('killall sc_serv_9002'); header ('Location: "desired path after executing command');` ''

That way I control the shoutcast ports. I have tried to do the same with icecast, but I can't. Because I want to do it like this, to avoid being accessing the console and executing each manual one as it would be with this command ```` `/home/icecast/8002/init.d/icecast2 start``` It should be noted that this is not the default path to start icecast, since the original is: ```` `/etc/init.d/icecast2 start``` but since I have created my folders for each ports, I can only start them by console and I want to use php to start it by calling the file start8002 .php of icecast by means of a button.

It should be noted that I tested the code that printed the result for me and it sent me as a response that the command was executed and it printed that icecast was starting. But it doesn't start.

development platform, VPS with ** UBUNTU 18.4 and ubuntu 20 **

Thank you who can give me a hand.

Comment: What you need to do is create an XML config file.  Use something like DOMDocument (I think this is what the module is called in PHP?), and modify the config as required.  Then, export that file and execute the Icecast server from there.

Comment: I have everything set to the path / home / icecast / 8002.
I can only start it by command in console, but not with php. and I did not understand what he meant to me.  in the folder 8002, there are all the icecast files to start icecast with port 8002,